# Horizontal and Vertical spacing in itemize environment

Tags: itemize, enumitem

I am trying to adjust the itemize environment. With the following code I get a result as seen below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.4cm,right=1.4cm,top=1.4cm,bottom=1.4cm,footskip=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\bullet$} % costume itemize
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\relbar$} % costume itemize
\usepackage{enumitem} % define itemize

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[a.] First
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,itemindent=-0.4cm,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,align=left]
      \item \lipsum[1]
      \item \lipsum[2]
    \end{itemize}
  \item[b.] Second;

  \item[c.] Third;
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As can be seen in the resulting output, the `itemindent=-0.4cm` only affects the first line in the 'Lorem ipsum...' text that follows. The second line keeps it's horizontal spacing without change. My intention is however, to shift everything more to the left so that the whole `item \lipsum[1]` text is at the same horizontal position as the 1st line.

I also tried to remove the vertical white space between `\item[a.] First` and `\item \lipsum[1]` with the command `topsep=0pt` but it seems to not have done anything. There still is the gap between the two itemize environments.
Does someone know a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.4cm,right=1.4cm,top=1.4cm,bottom=1.4cm,footskip=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\bullet$} % costume itemize
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\relbar$} % costume itemize
\usepackage{enumitem} % define itemize

\begin{document}

\begin{description}%[nosep]
  \item[a.] First
    \begin{itemize}[nosep,topsep=-1ex,leftmargin=0.5\labelsep]
      \item \lipsum[1]
      \item \lipsum[2]
    \end{itemize}
  \item[b.] Second;

  \item[c.] Third;
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]